# Why texture (GL_TEXTURE_2D) cannot work with (VertexArray) VAO

Tags: opengl, texture2d, vao

I am working on a project with openGL part. The scenegraph part is based on core OpenGL1.0 and still use glBegin and glEnd.
Now I am adding new stuff on it and has to use VAO. I am a beginner and use `QOpenGLFunctions_3_0` because I cannot find gl3.h from openGL registry
The problem is now that I use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` with `glBegin(GL_QUADS)`, it works,
and I draw single `glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);` it works too.
But when I use `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and `glDrawElements( GL_QUADS...` , the texture is not generated correctly. Please tell me the right way to use it. 
Here is thd code

```
/** draws Texture */

class TextureNode
    : public Node
{

public:

TextureNode( const cv::Mat& mat )
{
    m_mat = mat;
}
TextureNode( const std::string& id, const cv::Mat& mat )
    : Node( id )
{
    m_mat = mat;
}

~TextureNode()
{
    //glDeleteTextures( 1, &m_texture[0] );
}

void init( TraversalContext& context )
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();


    struct Vertex {
      GLfloat position[3];
      GLfloat texcoord[2];
      GLfloat normal[3];
    };
    const int NUM_VERTS = 4;
    const int NUM_INDICES = 4;
    Vertex vertexdata[NUM_VERTS] = {
        {{0,    0,  0},         {0,0},  {0,0,1}},
        {{0,    100,    0},     {0,1},  {0,0,1}},
        {{100,  100,    0},     {1,1},  {0,0,1}},
        {{100,  0,  0},         {1,0},  {0,0,1}},
    };
    GLubyte indexdata[NUM_INDICES] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

            // Create and bind a VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_quadVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_quadVAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_quadPositionVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_quadPositionVBO);

    // copy data into the buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_VERTS * sizeof(Vertex), vertexdata, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_quadIndexVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_quadIndexVBO);

    // copy data into the buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NUM_INDICES * sizeof(GLubyte), indexdata, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // Create and bind a texture

    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);                 // Create The Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture); 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, m_mat.cols, m_mat.rows, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  m_mat.data);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);

    //////// At this point the VAO is set up with two vertex attributes
    //////// referencing the same buffer object, and another buffer object
    //////// as source for index data. We can now unbind the VAO, go do
    //////// something else, and bind it again later when we want to render
    //////// with it.

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 
    glBindVertexArray(NULL);    

    //////glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL);  
    //glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL );
    //////glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL); 


}

/** apply transformation */
void doWork( TraversalContext& context )
{

//QTime time;
//time.start();
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindVertexArray( m_quadVAO );



    //glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);



    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + m_texture - 1 );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
    glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //  glColor3d( 0,0,0 );
    //  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2d( 0, 0 );
    //  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2d( 0, m_mat.rows );
    //  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2d( m_mat.cols, m_mat.rows );
    //  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2d( m_mat.cols, 0 );
    //glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
}
void destroy( TraversalContext& context )
{

    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &m_quadVAO );
    glDeleteTextures(1,&m_texture);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_quadPositionVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_quadTexcoordVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_quadIndexVBO);
}


protected:

GLuint m_quadVAO;
GLuint m_quadPositionVBO;
GLuint m_quadTexcoordVBO;
GLuint m_quadIndexVBO;
GLuint m_texture;
///** list of vertices */
GLfloat m_vertices[4][2];
cv::Mat m_mat;
};
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `gl3.h`, at least not in vanilla OpenGL. You have to load the extension functions, either manually or by using something like `GLEW`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That's only true on Windows. On other platforms, you simply include the OpenGL headers, and call the functions.

Comment: It's also true on many platforms that use GLX (e.g. Linux). OS X is really the oddball among OpenGL implementations, since the library you link to at build-time contains all of the symbols regardless what hardware driver is installed. In any case, `OpenGL/gl3.h` is kind of an Apple construct; if you want the equivalent from the OpenGL registry, it would be `GL/glcorearb.h`

Answer (score 0):

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
```

This is using the generic vertex attributes, but that only makes sense when using sharers, and afaik don't work with the fixed-function pipeline. Either create a shader to use them, or use `glVertexPointer`, `glTexCoordPointer`, and/or `glNormalPointer` instead.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + m_texture - 1 );
```

This is incorrect. `glActiveTexture` selects which texture unit to bind to; it does not use texture names at all. Since you're not using shaders, this should just be `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)`.

Side note: You don't need to use an index buffer for drawing a single quad; you can use [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlDrawArrays) instead.

Comment: I tried glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0), it is the same result. And, I also tried glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4 ); it is still the same, only one color, no texture

Comment: the last parameter is how many vertices are to be drawn you should use `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4 );`

Comment: now i use    { glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
  glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texcoord));  
  glNormalPointer( GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal)); } and dann    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4 );   then I cannot saw the quard at all

Comment: it seems that glVertexPointer doesnot work, if I use glVertexAttribPointer, at least I have a quad, although the texture is not shown, but if I use glVertexPointer, I got nothing at all.

Comment: @langbeibei: If you're going to use `glVertexPointer` and friends, you need to enable the client states such as `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` instead of using `glEnableVertexAttribArray (...)`. Generic attribute arrays are not supposed to alias to the client arrays in _modern_ (GLSL-based) OpenGL, but in older GL implementations it was understood that generic attribute **0** aliased to `glVertexPointer`, for example; avoid that and write standard compliant code by not mixing and matching the two things.